# Как дать класс дочернему элементу конкретного родителя(несколько родителей с одинаковым классом)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка, swiper

Есть свайпер со слайдами. Все слайды имеют одинаковые классы. В слайдах есть ul, в которой показаны только первые четыре li, а остальные должны показывать после нажатия на кнопку "Подробнее...". Но в прописанном мной JS-коде класс даётся всем li во всех родителях, когда как только надо в слайде где была нажата кнопка.

```
//HTML
 <div class="swiper-slide first-slide ">
                                <h4>Подготовка к школе</h4>
                                <span class="tenge-price">30 000 тг</span>
                                <div class="age-and-time">
                                    <p>4-6 лет</p>
                                    <p class="mb60"><span>3 занятия</span> в неделю по <span>3 ч.</span></p>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>Обучение чтению </li>
                                        <li>Письмо</li>
                                        <li>Математика</li>
                                        <li>Английский язык</li>
                                        <li>Развитие речи</li>
                                        <li>Концентрация внимания</li>
                                        <li>Усвоение изучаемого материала</li>
                                        <li>Различные техники запоминания</li>
                                        <li>Развитие логико-математического мышления</li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <button  class="more">Подробнее...</button>
                                    <a href="#">Выбрать</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="swiper-slide second-slide">
                                <h4>скорочтение</h4>
                                <span class="tenge-price">27 000 тг</span>
                                <div class="age-and-time">
                                    <p>6-15 лет</p>
                                    <p class="mb60"><span>3 занятия</span> в неделю по <span>1 ч.</span></p>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>Увеличение скорости чтения</li>
                                        <li>Артикуляция</li>
                                        <li>Развитие речи</li>
                                        <li>Развитие внимания</li>
                                        <li>Увеличение поля зрения</li>
                                        <li>Увеличение словарного запаса</li>
                                        <li>Понимание прочитанного</li>
                                        <li>Пересказ</li>
                                        <li>Различные техники понимания</li>
                                        <li>Пробный урок и диагностика БЕСПЛАТНО</li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <a href="#">Выбрать</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

```
//CSS
.age-and-time ul li:nth-child(n + 5) {
    display: none;
}
.li_on{
    display: block !important;
}
.more {
    font-family: Commissioner;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 29px;
    letter-spacing: 0em;
    color: #018FA3;
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
}


.more__none{
    display: none;
}
```

```
//JS

 var more = $('.more');
   var li_off = $('.age-and-time ul li:nth-child(n + 5)')

   more.click(function(){
    more.toggleClass('more__none');
    li_off.toggleClass('li_on');
   });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если класс нужен только для того чтобы показать\скрыть элементы, лучше воспользоваться функцией toggle()..

```js
var more = $('.more');

more.click(function() {
  //$(this).toggle(); //скрыть кнопку подробнее
  $("ul li:nth-child(n + 5)", this.parentNode).toggle();
  
  //more.toggleClass('more__none');
  //$("ul li:nth-child(n + 5)", this.parentNode).toggleClass('li_on');
});
```

```css
.age-and-time ul li:nth-child(n + 5) {
  display: none;
}

.more {
  font-family: Commissioner;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 29px;
  letter-spacing: 0em;
  color: #018FA3;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="swiper-slide first-slide ">
  <h4>Подготовка к школе</h4>
  <span class="tenge-price">30 000 тг</span>
  <div class="age-and-time">
    <p>4-6 лет</p>
    <p class="mb60"><span>3 занятия</span> в неделю по <span>3 ч.</span></p>
    <ul>
      <li>Обучение чтению </li>
      <li>Письмо</li>
      <li>Математика</li>
      <li>Английский язык</li>
      <li>Развитие речи</li>
      <li>Концентрация внимания</li>
      <li>Усвоение изучаемого материала</li>
      <li>Различные техники запоминания</li>
      <li>Развитие логико-математического мышления</li>
    </ul>
    <button class="more">Подробнее...</button>
    <a href="#">Выбрать</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="swiper-slide second-slide">
  <h4>скорочтение</h4>
  <span class="tenge-price">27 000 тг</span>
  <div class="age-and-time">
    <p>6-15 лет</p>
    <p class="mb60"><span>3 занятия</span> в неделю по <span>1 ч.</span></p>
    <ul>
      <li>Увеличение скорости чтения</li>
      <li>Артикуляция</li>
      <li>Развитие речи</li>
      <li>Развитие внимания</li>
      <li>Увеличение поля зрения</li>
      <li>Увеличение словарного запаса</li>
      <li>Понимание прочитанного</li>
      <li>Пересказ</li>
      <li>Различные техники понимания</li>
      <li>Пробный урок и диагностика БЕСПЛАТНО</li>
    </ul>
    <button class="more">Подробнее...</button>
    <a href="#">Выбрать</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: большое спасибо! а то с JS я знаком поверхностно

Comment: @Burr_DI На здоровье! :)